# Remove padding between the list item in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

Want to remove padding bettween list item in angular material as it contains more screen space.[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-list?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an other height for mat-list-item ( currently the height is 48px)

```
.wrapper .mat-list-item {
  height: 20px;
}
```